# How to use Repo.get with select like in Repo.one

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm not sure this is possible but I like the fact that Repo.get is returning a Struct.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
Repo.get(User, id, select: [:id, :name])
```

Like in:

```
Repo.one(from u in User, where: u.id == ^id, select: [u.id, u.name]
```

But with Repo.get, I cannot figure out from the Ecto docs if it's possible and how to achieve this.

Context: I'm using Guardian and the serializer does something like:

```
def from_token("User:" <> id), do: {:ok, Repo.get(User, id,)}
```

So when I call `current_resource(conn)` I get a convenient user struct. But this query return all the infos of the user from the db which I'm trying to filter (for instance I don't want the encrypted password in my `current_resource(conn)`.

Comment: So you want a list containing the `id` and the `name` instead of a struct, and `nil` if a User with the given doesn't exist, but using `Repo.get`?

Comment: I would like a struct/nil like with Repo.get. The list is not "the desired behavior". The id and name are just exemples.

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, Repo.get is returning a struct whereas Repo.one doesn't. But I can use select with Repo.one and I cannot figure out how to use select with Repo.get.

Comment: So you want a struct but with only specific fields? The rest of the fields of the struct should be `nil` then?

Comment: Yes exactly! (It's sunday maybe my question isn't as clear as I think ;) )

Comment: Try this (you might need to import `Ecto.Query`): `from(User) |> select([:id, :name]) |> Repo.get(id)`. (I'm not sure why this works but it seems to be working.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try as soon as possible. Yes for the import, I already import it to try some idea.

Comment: It's working, if you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dogbert mention in the comments the solution is:

```
import Ecto.Query

from(User) |> select([:id, :name]) |> Repo.get(id)
```

And inside the guardian serializer:

```
import Ecto.Query

....

def from_token("User:" <> id), do: {:ok, from(User) |> select([:id, :name]) |> Repo.get(id)}

.....
```

From the [Ecto.Repo](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#content) docs:

> get(queryable, id, opts)
>   get(queryable :: Ecto.Queryable.t, id :: term, opts :: Keyword.t) ::
>     Ecto.Schema.t |
>     nil |
>     no_return
>
> Fetches a single struct from the data store where the primary key matches the given id.
>
> Returns nil if no result was found. If the struct in the queryable has no or more than one primary key, it will raise an argument error.

As mention the first argument that `get/3` is waiting for is a queryable. That's why we can construct the queryable with `from(User) |> select([:id, :name])` and then passes it to `Repo.get(id)`

This will return a struct based on the `user` model.

And as the [phoenix-framework docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models) mentionned:

> Each model defines the fields of our schema as well as their types.
>   They each define a struct with the same fields in our schema.

So the struct that is returned will have all field described in the model/schema but with nil values where we don't select them.